# Are multiple executed queries in a websql transaction run asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, sqlite

[An online tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm) shows this transaction:

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
   tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (id unique, log)');
   tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (1, "foobar")');
   tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (2, "logmsg")');
});
```

I've now read in multiple threads that these queries (each executeSql) get run asynchronously within the transaction.

If that's true, don't we run a slight risk of trying to insert before the table is even created?

Or is that incorrect? Do the queries get run serially within a transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the actual execution is asynchronous, the statements are queued up inside the transaction, so multiple statements are serialized.

Comment: So the second query will not begin until the first query completes?
I'm confused by what you mean by the execution is asynchronous but the statements are serialized.

Comment: "Asynchronous" means that the queries might not be finished when `executeSql` returns.

Comment: Got it, so the answer is "Yes, the inserts may happen before the create statement completes"